# how do I configure VS code to build in Release mode (clang + macOS)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, build, clang, release-mode

I am new to VS code. I have configured it using Clang on macOS using the provided [VS code documentation] (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac)

It works, I can build and debug. Great!

My question is: how do I configure VS Code to build in Release mode? I don't seem to be able to find any info in the documentation or a tutorial on how to do it

In case it helps, this is the way *tasks.json* looks right now

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "clang++ build active file",
        "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
        "args": [
          "-std=c++17",
          "-stdlib=libc++",
          "-g",
          "-v",
          "${file}",
          "${workspaceFolder}/source/*.cpp",
          "${workspaceFolder}/FFTreal/*.cpp",

           "-I.",       

          "-L",
          "${workspaceFolder}/BassLibrary",
          "-lbass",

          "-o",
          "${workspaceFolder}/final.out",

        ],
        "options": {
          "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
        "group": {
          "kind": "build",
          "isDefault": true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, for the last answer...

So first of all, I need to claim that I'm not really familiar to **Clang Family**, but I did some [research](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks-appendix) and found that there are two special groups out in `tasks.json` which VSCode provides: Build and Test. So, I guess that we need to build it in release mode manually where again I don't have any confidence on me...

I found that you can build your Clang scripts using CMake. CMake is simply a builder tool to help you reassemble your whole code, including libraries, dependencies, modules etc.

So, I'm not sure if that'll be possible but you can change your `tasks.json` configuration from Clang++ to CMake, maybe?

First of all, for a quick answer, I edited your `tasks.json` snippet to this:

```
{
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "cmake init",
      "type": "shell",
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
      },
      "command": "/path/to/cmake",
      "args": [
        "-S",
        "${cwd}",
        "-B",
        "${cwd}/build"
      ],
      "problemMatcher": [
        "$gcc"
      ],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      }
    },
    {
      "label": "cmake release builder",
      "type": "shell",
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
      },
      "command": "/path/to/cmake",
      "args": [
        "--build",
        "${workspaceRoot}/build",
        "--config",
        "Release"
      ],
      "problemMatcher": [
        "$gcc"
      ],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

What it does is, basically CMake scans your project folder and create configuration files via the `cmake init` task. After that, when you run `cmake release builder`, the task will assume that you have a build folder - which you can change easily - and creates a compact executable file, in `build/Release`.

But also, in order to use CMake, you need to create a `CMakeLists.txt` file whose baseName is case-sensitive. So, I created a really simple CMake configuration file which you can add your source files manually, unfortunately, like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)  # CMake version check
project(simple_example)               # Create project "simple_example"
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)            # Enable c++14 standard
set(SOURCE_FILES test.cpp add.cpp)    # Append source files

# Add executable target with source files listed in SOURCE_FILES variable
add_executable(simple_example ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Finally, to make this process **REAL**, you need to go `Terminal > Run Build Task` in VSCode.

I'm not really sure that you can use Clang compiler to build a whole application, like an .exe file in Windows. During the research, I focused a lot on the difference between compiler and builder which I recommend to look it up!

I hope that I used English in a comprehensible way and not made confused.

Comment: Ah, also I forgot to tell that you can use a more "graphical" interface in VSCode, which is `CMake` and `CMake Tools` in the extensions. You can select whether Debug or Release  from the status bar and also select a kit to compile.

Comment: Thanks Roni. That points me to the right direction

Comment: I'm sorry that I couldn't make a complete answer. I hope it aided you to take step to solve your problem!